# How to improve my mentioned question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Read from file and write to cout in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220658/read-from-file-and-write-to-cout-in-one-line)

As you can see, it has received a lot of downvotes. I don't understand why. The answer was received well. This question has not been asked before. Is with the way I have asked it too vague? Or is it just at trend to downvote C++ questions? I believe my question was simple and unique enough.

Comment: Nails on a black-board to programmers that have learned the Hard Way™ to keep their source code readable.  They don't think anybody should do that, thus likely to mark the question to be unhelpful.  Next time you ask a question like that, consider to explain why it is important to you.

Comment: As well as giving a justification for wanting to do something that many would see as a retrograde step (and _often_ it would be; but not always), you might also be more precise in your requirements: you _presumably_ mean "_in one statement_" since "_in one line_" can be achieved simply by putting both statements on one line! – `fscanf(fp,"%d",&n); std::cout<<n<<std::endl;`

Answer (score 23):

As I was the one who wrote the answer there, I tried to generalize your problem a bit with showing a valid use case, why you might probably do what you want as shown in your very short example.

You could improve your question going into the same direction and try showing a valid use case you can imagine using that syntax.

This will make your question more useful for future research, in case someone hits that same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A kid is able to produce unique questions every minute. Are such questions valuable? Not really. He just see something new, combine it with something he knows and here is 100500th question ready.

> I believe my question was simple and unique enough.

When asking question try to think about its value: how likely its the problem to someone else, how big is the problem, do you really need answer to your question or maybe there is another question (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295)), how well you present it.

Asking good question is a lot of work.

Your question is as its currently asked is useless: it's an interesting task for some more advanced brains, but solution is totally useless, only works as a prove, what brains are advanced.

Why do you need 2 things in one line? What is **the problem** with them not being in same line? This is missing and value of question is something like `-20`.

There could be a totally different solution to that problem which you are trying to solve by having 2 things in one line. Experts hate to answer vague questions. Simple doesn't means it's clear, you just forgot to add important details.

Why the answer receive upvotes? Because it's good. Perhaps because its un-obvious solution (I am not c++ expert), perhaps because there is also missing problem, which makes your question more valuable.